# Receiving notification of a JFace Action being activated

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

In my Eclipse RCP project, I create a JFace [Action](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/IAction.html) and then add it to my [Form](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/forms/ManagedForm.html)'s [ToolBarManager](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/ToolBarManager.html). What is the correct mechanism for my *Form* to be notified of the Action's activation? The Action itself is self-contained and performs what it needs to perform. But as a side-effect I'd also like the Form to be able to react, something like an 'onButtonClicked' callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the API `addSelectionListener(SelectionListener)`. If you say the action is wrapper, then you delegate methods if needed.

You are aware of the action selection with the `getSelection()` method.